# Is it possible to query off a Sybase table and join with an Oracle dimension table?

Tags: oracle11g, left-join, sap-ase

Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT s.*, o.*
FROM SybaseServer.Database.Schema.Table s

LEFT JOIN OracleServer.Schema.Table o
on s.SyabseID = o.OracleID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an Oracle Transparent Gateway to allow an Oracle query to use a dB link towards a Sybase ASE server.